# using python 3 to code for a LED

Tags: gpio, python

i am trying to use python shell to turn ON a LED ,connected on port 4,i have installed GPIO to the pi but still i am getting this error 
plz help 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you wrote 'setpu' instead of 'setup' on line 3.